# express SSE endpoint thread keeps running after being destroyed

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using SSE on a nodejs server with express and this library (https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/sse-express)
On the server i have an endpoint that waits for a client to connect and then I can send messages to the client without problems

```js
router.get('/updates/:imei', sseExpress(), (req,res) => {
    var message = {};
    openConnections["skd"] = res;
    //connections.push(res);
    
    setInterval(() => {    
        //console.log("EVENTY");
        
        console.log(req.params.imei);
        message.streaming = "false";
        message.apk = "false";
        res.sse({
            event: 'message from server',
            data: message
        });
    }, updates_interval);

    req.on("close", function() {
    console.log("Closing");

        delete openConnections["skd"];
      });

});
```

The client is an android app that connects to the endpoint and keeps listening updates.

So far everything works just fine.
But if I close the android app req.on("close" triggers but the endpoint stays running despite the fact that I added it to a weakmap and destroyed it.

[image]

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should kill the interval when the socket is closed

```js
router.get('/updates/:imei', sseExpress(), (req,res) => {
    
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {    
        let message = {};
        message.streaming = "false";
        message.apk = "false";
        res.sse({
            event: 'message from server',
            data: message
        });
    }, updates_interval);

    req.on("close", function() {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
    });
});
```

Comment: But its weird because if I replace the interval with something like an event the event still triggers too, which doesn't happen before the client connects, so it makes me think the socket stays open somehow

Comment: The problem is the same if you replace the interval with listening to an event from i.e. an event queue or database. If you subscribe to that event, your database cannot know that the sse socket closed if you don't tell it. What are you listening to?

Comment: Its an event triggered from a post but I only had it for testing. in the case of an event should I kill the event somehow then?

Comment: yes, most likely with `removeEventListener`